# insert multiple rows using one forigenk value in form

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have a form as like below.

[image]

there is one dropdown for select project project name. once select project name and then enter other field and submit form.now i want to insert data into table with project id.
my db structure as below.

id | project_id | item |description |qty |unit| rate| l_cost|l_hrs|amount

according to my code project_id insert only for first row. this is the array which i'm getting using print_r

Array ( [0] => Array ( [project_id] => 1 [staff_id] => 2 [item_no] => 1 [description] => 1 [qty] => 1 [unit] => [rate] => 1 [laboure_hrs] => 1 [laboure_cost] => 1 [amount] => 2 ) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSd7A.png) => Array ( [project_id] => [staff_id] => 2 [item_no] => 2 [description] => 2 [qty] => 2 [unit] => [rate] => 2 [laboure_hrs] => 2 [laboure_cost] => 2 [amount] => 8 ) [2] => Array ( [project_id] => [staff_id] => 2 [item_no] => 3 [description] => 3 [qty] => 3 [unit] => [rate] => 3 [laboure_hrs] => 3 [laboure_cost] => 3 [amount] => 18 ) )

my code is as below

**view**

```
 <form class="form-inline" role="form" id="frmadd" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/boq_controller/create" method="POST">
<!--project-->


<span><b>Project Name</b></span>
    <?php
       $attributes = 'class = "form-control" id = "project" style="width:100%; height:35px;"';
        echo form_dropdown('project[]',$project, set_value('project'), $attributes);?>

 <!--project-->

    <!-- boq_tbl // field list-->
   <table class="table" id="boq_tbl">
                   <tbody>
<!--<form class="form-inline" role="form" id="frmadd" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/boq_controller/create" method="POST">-->


    <tr class="txtMult">

       <td><input type="text" name="work_product_id[]" class="form-control" id="work_product_id" placeholder="" style="width:60px;" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="work_item_description[]" class="form-control" id="work_item_description" placeholder="" style="width:350px;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="" class="form-control val1" style="width:80px;" /></td>
        <td><select style=" height: 28px; width: 70px; border-radius: 2px;" name="unit[]" >
            <option value="" selected> </option>
            <option value="cube">cube</option>
            <option value="sq.ft">sq.ft</option>
            <option value="Cwts">Cwts</option>
            <option value="Gal" >Gal</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" class="form-control val2" style="width:80px;"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="laboure_hrs[]" id="" class="form-control val3" style="width:80px;"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"name="laboure_cost[]" id="" class="form-control val4" style="width:80px;"/></td>


        <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtmultTotal" name="txtmultTotal[]" style="width:80px;" placeholder="0.00" class="multTotal">
<!--            <input type="text" class="multTotal" placeholder="0.00">-->
        </td>
        <td><?php                                           
//hidden value user session id
echo form_hidden('staff_id[]',($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']) );

?>  </td>
    </tr>

     </tbody>
       </table> 
<p align="right">
    Grand Total# <span id="grandTotal">0.00</span> <input type="text" id="txtgrandTotal" name="txtgrandTotal">
    <button id="insert-more" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">ADD</button>

</p>

<div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btn btn-success" value="submit">
                </div>

</form>
```

**controller**

```
public function create(){


           if ($_POST) 
   {
        $project_id=$this->input->post('project');
        $staff_id=$this->input->post('staff_id');
       $item_no=$this->input->post('work_product_id');
        $description=$this->input->post('work_item_description');
        $qty=$this->input->post('quantity');
        $unit=$this->input->post('unit');
        $rate=$this->input->post('rate');
        $laboure_hrs=$this->input->post('laboure_hrs');
        $laboure_cost=$this->input->post('laboure_cost');
        $amount=$this->input->post('txtmultTotal');
        $data = array();
       for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->input->post('work_product_id')); $i++)
        {
           $data[$i] = array(
               'project_id' => $project_id[$i],
               'staff_id' => $staff_id[$i],
               'item_no' => $item_no[$i],
               'description' => $description[$i],
               'qty' => $qty[$i],
                'unit' => $unit[$i],
             'rate' => $rate[$i],
             'laboure_hrs' => $laboure_hrs[$i],
               'laboure_cost' => $laboure_cost[$i],
               'amount' => $amount[$i],
            );
       }
        $this->boq_model->create($data);
    }
```

**model**

```
function create($data) {
    $this->db->insert('boq', $data);
```

Comment: i want to insert all rows at once. once a select a project name it should be apper in all rows

Answer (score 0):

```
public function create() {
if($_POST) {
    $project_id   = $this->input->post('project');
    $staff_id     = $this->input->post('staff_id');
    $description  = $this->input->post('work_item_description');
    $qty          = $this->input->post('quantity');
    $unit         = $this->input->post('unit');
    $rate         = $this->input->post('rate');
    $laboure_hrs  = $this->input->post('laboure_hrs');
    $laboure_cost = $this->input->post('laboure_cost');
    $amount       = $this->input->post('txtmultTotal');
    $data         = array();

    $item_no      = $this->input->post('work_product_id');
    foreach($item_no as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key]       = array(
            'project_id'  => $project_id,
            'staff_id'    => $staff_id[$key],
            'item_no'     => $value,
            'description' => $description[$key],
            'qty'         => $qty[$key],
            'unit'        => $unit[$key],
            'rate'        => $rate[$key],
            'laboure_hrs' => $laboure_hrs[$key],
            'laboure_cost'=> $laboure_cost[$key],
            'amount'      => $amount[$key],
        );
    }
    $this->boq_model->create($data);
}
```

}

Comment: insert project_id for only very first row