# insert multiple records at once for single foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

based on [insert multiple rows using one forigenk value in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366230/insert-multiple-rows-using-one-forigenk-value-in-form)

[image]

according to above picture there is dropdown for select project.once select project and user will be able to add other details. now i want to do when form is submitting project_id (id map with project name in drop down)should insert with other rows.
but in my case project_id is inserting with only very first row. below result came when i print the array .

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [project_id] => 1 [staff_id] => 2 [item_no] =>
>   1 [description] => 1 [qty] => 1 [unit] => cube [rate] => 1
>   [laboure_hrs] => 1 [laboure_cost] => 1 [amount] => 2 ) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3H9P.png) => Array (
>   [project_id] => [staff_id] => 2 [item_no] => 2 [description] => 2
>   [qty] => 2 [unit] => sq.ft [rate] => 2 [laboure_hrs] => 2
>   [laboure_cost] => 2 [amount] => 8 ) [2] => Array ( [project_id] =>
>   [staff_id] => 2 [item_no] => 3 [description] => 3 [qty] => 3 [unit] =>
>   cube [rate] => 3 [laboure_hrs] => 3 [laboure_cost] => 3 [amount] => 18
>   ) )

how i can pass project_id for another fields. my code is below

controler

```
public function create(){

//    validate fields
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('work_product_id', 'Work Product Id', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('work_item_description', 'Work Item Description', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('quantity', 'Quantity', 'required');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('rate', 'Rate', 'required|numeric');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('laboure_hrs', 'Laboure Hrs', 'required|numeric');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('laboure_cost', 'Laboure Cost', 'required|numeric');

           if ($_POST) 
   {
        $project_id=$this->input->post('project');
        $staff_id=$this->input->post('staff_id');
        $item_no=$this->input->post('work_product_id');
        $description=$this->input->post('work_item_description');
        $qty=$this->input->post('quantity');
        $unit=$this->input->post('unit');
        $rate=$this->input->post('rate');
        $laboure_hrs=$this->input->post('laboure_hrs');
        $laboure_cost=$this->input->post('laboure_cost');
        $amount=$this->input->post('txtmultTotal');
           $data= [];

   for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->input->post('work_product_id')); $i++)
    {
       $data[$i] = array(
           'project_id' => $project_id
           'staff_id' => $staff_id[$i],
           'item_no' => $item_no[$i],
           'description' => $description[$i],
           'qty' => $qty[$i],
           'unit' => $unit[$i],
           'rate' => $rate[$i],
           'laboure_hrs' => $laboure_hrs[$i],
           'laboure_cost' => $laboure_cost[$i],
           'amount' => $amount[$i],
        );
       }
        print_r($data);
       $this->boq_model->create($data);
    }      

}
```

model

```
function create($data){

     $this->db->insert_batch('boq',$data);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your html, the project_id is not a control array. So what you should do is to retrieve the project_id before the loop and use it in the loop or remove the [$i] in front of the project_id in the loop

Comment: sir i have edited my code as u said. but  nothing happen when i click the submit button. i have already edit my question.can you please help me.

Comment: Change $data=array('project_id' => $project_id) to $data=[] and in the loop in the creation of the array put project_id' => $project_id it should work

Comment: great sir. but i have some problem with model. but data doesn't insert into the table. is there any problem in my model.

Comment: here is my model code is like below. 
function create($data){
        $this->db->insert_batch('boq',$data);
    }

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to insert a single row into your `project` table, and then insert several rows into your `item` table using the value of your `project_id` column as a foreign key.

(With respect, your question is hard to understand; you may get a better answer than mine if you get help editing it from someone with good English-language skills.)

Here's what you do.

First, INSERT a row into your `project` table.  Do not mention the `project_id` column in your INSERT query, so MySQL will assign an autoincrementing primary key.

```
  INSERT INTO project (name, whatever) VALUES (?, ?);
```

Then, [retrieve the value of the autoincrementing ID using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) as follows.

```
  SET @project_id := LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Then, insert rows into your `item` table using that value.

```
 INSERT INTO item (project_id, description, qty, whatever)
           VALUES (@project_id, ?, ?, ?)
```

The trick is to retrieve the value of [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) right after your master-table insertion and store it in the [MySQL user-defined variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) `@project_id`. Then you use it for each insertion into your detail table.

Comment: project_id is not a primary key.it is a forigen key