# insert multiple rows into the database through nested array in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

according to [insert multiple rows using one forigenk value in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366230/insert-multiple-rows-using-one-forigenk-value-in-form)

i want to insert multiple data at once through nested array. in my case data doesn't insert into the database. and no error messages to display.my code is below.

any one can please help me to slove this problem.

controller

```
public function create(){

//    validate fields
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('work_product_id', 'Work Product Id', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('work_item_description', 'Work Item Description', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('quantity', 'Quantity', 'required');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('rate', 'Rate', 'required|numeric');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('laboure_hrs', 'Laboure Hrs', 'required|numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('laboure_cost', 'Laboure Cost', 'required|numeric');

//            getting value of input fields


          if ($_POST) 
   {
        $project_id=$this->input->post('project');
        $staff_id=$this->input->post('staff_id');
        $item_no=$this->input->post('work_product_id');
        $description=$this->input->post('work_item_description');
        $qty=$this->input->post('quantity');
        $unit=$this->input->post('unit');
        $rate=$this->input->post('rate');
        $laboure_hrs=$this->input->post('laboure_hrs');
        $laboure_cost=$this->input->post('laboure_cost');
        $amount=$this->input->post('txtmultTotal');

        $data=[];

       for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->input->post('work_product_id')); $i++)
        {
           $data[$i] = array(
               'project_id' => $project_id,
               'staff_id' => $staff_id[$i],
               'item_no' => $item_no[$i],
               'description' => $description[$i],
               'qty' => $qty[$i],
               'unit' => $unit[$i],
               'rate' => $rate[$i],
               'laboure_hrs' => $laboure_hrs[$i],
               'laboure_cost' => $laboure_cost[$i],
               'amount' => $amount[$i],
            );
       }
        print_r($data);
        $this->boq_model->create($data);
    }
}
```

model

```
function create($data){
$this -> db-> insert_batch('boq',$data);
}
```

Comment: Please check your error_reporting. Also, please check with $this->db->_error_message();

Comment: nothing happen when i click submit button

Comment: check whether the function is working by echo some thing

Comment: yes fuction is working. when i comment $this->boq_model->create($data); and then print array using print_r($data). it works fine

Comment: echo last query and paste on comment. echo $this->db->last_query();

Comment: nothing to show. i have print the array 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [project_id] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [staff_id] => 2 [item_no] => 1 [description] => [qty] => [unit] => [rate] => [laboure_hrs] => [laboure_cost] => [amount] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [project_id] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [staff_id] => 2 [item_no] => 2 [description] => [qty] => [unit] => [rate] => [laboure_hrs] => [laboure_cost] => [amount] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [project_id] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [staff_id] => 2 [item_no] => 3 [description] => [qty] => [unit] => [rate] => [laboure_hrs] => [laboure_cost] => [amount] => 0 ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this
Comment `//$data=[];`

and in foreach

```
 $data[] = array(
 //ur data
   );
```

Comment: nothing happen. i think there was error in my model

Comment: there is problem in ur array have u given  $this->input->post('project'); as array in view

Comment: <?php
       $attributes = 'class = "form-control" id = "project" style="width:100%; height:35px;"';
        echo form_dropdown('project[]',$project, set_value('project'), $attributes);?>

Comment: thankx. i removed [] of project. now it works. thank u soo much